# Express app.use() is not handling routes in separate file "Cannot GET /"

Tags: node.js, express, routes, backend

Result is "Cannot GET /"

Both files are in the same folder and if i use routes directly in the app.js file it works.
app.js

```
//ROUTING
var router = require('./index');
app.use('/*', router);
//ROUTING END
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = new express.Router();
var user = require("./controllers/user");
var products = require("./controllers/products");
router.get("/", products.products_list);
router.get("/user/profile", user.profile);
router.get("/user/signup", user.signup_redirect);
router.get("/user/logout", user.logout_redirect);
router.post("/user/signup", user.signup_post);
router.get("/user/login",user.login_redirect);
router.post("/user/login", user.login_post);

module.exports = router
```

Comment: I can not see `/` route in your `Router` file, you need to define `router.get("/", user.someFunction);`

Comment: @ArifKhan I have it. It's not full code

Comment: Remove the `*` from middleware `app.use('/*', router);` which becomes `app.use('/', router);`  even you can skip first argument as you are not mounting any endpoint `app.use(router);` will also work and recommended